# Huge continous (re)import and refresh of data in pricing table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, import, bigdata, rdbms

I have a large dataset (~2.5 million rows), which needs to be (re-)imported continously into a MySQL table "price_list". All tables are InnoDB. Currently I'm using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE", because those datasets come from csv files:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.csv'
INTO TABLE `price_list`
(...)
(...)
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Example of a table in in db "price_list":

```
hotel_id | room_category            | price 1 person | price 2nd person     | <other meta info>

1        | single room (w/o window) | 150€           | 200€                 | ...
2        | single room (w window)   | 170€           | 220€                 | ...
3        | single room (rooftop)    | 240€           | 250€                 | ...
4        | single room (whirlpool)  | 200€           | 280€                 | ...
5        | double room (w/o window) | 200€           | 220€                 | ...
6        | double room (w window)   | 240€           | 260€                 | ...
7        | double room (rooftop)    | 280€           | 300€                 | ...
8        | double room (whirlpool)  | 320€           | 340€                 | ...
(...)
```

Based on this data I need to update table "offers" (the table sits in another database, user of has "price_list" no access to "offers" and its technically not possible to give the proper access) with refreshed pricings. Pricings change a lot and we need to reimport those data every 15 minutes.

```
id  |       offer_name           |   price_single_room    |    price_double_room
1   |  WHIRLPOOL OFFER SINGLES   |         200€           |          200€
```

In the above example the price for the "best" single room (with a whirlpool) was choosen (200€). The 2nd price is not needed in this offer, but is calculated on purpose (and can be deactived if wanted).

My current solution is that I fetch all offers from the "offers" table in PHP, which are marked as active, and loop through them (*oof*). Each offer has 6 columns for different pricings (e.g. hotel has different rooms available; column 1 is the best price for single room, column 2 is the best price for double room, ...) that needs to be looked up.

Currently we have around 10.000 active offers which means I'm sending the following amount to the database server: 10.000 queries * 6 queries to look up best pricings per offer.

When I execute those queries on the same server (no network latency etc.) the performance is not the worst (the whole job takes around 5 minutes (importing ~2.5m rows, refresh pricings, ...)), but since the data is growing, we want to split up database and webserver. I now realized that the part where I'm refreshing the prices produces a lot of overhead with network and is very slow since each request from webserver to db server takes around 0.025s (25minutes only for refreshing prices).

I thought about the following solution(s):

- move the table "offers" to the same database "price_list" = working, but still very slow since the database server is not on the same machine as the webserver = network latency is the bottleneck.
- write a stored procedure, which is triggered by PHP and the database server does the job.

Does someone have experience with those recurring data loads and maybe a solution for my given problem? The goal is to reduce timings and split web and database server.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to make a schema that's better suited for your querying and convert your raw import format to that schema during or after import. One trick that works is staging a new table (e.g. `offers__updated`), loading data into it, doing any clean-up, then swapping: `RENAME TABLE offers TO offers__old, offers__updated TO offers` meaning there's no long table locks.

Comment: Hi @tadman,
thanks for your reply. Currently I'm already doing this with the "price_list" table; I have two databases which are holding the same tables; one is the "live" / "active" db and one is the "temporary" / "inactive" db. The cronjob is working only in inside the inactive db (prevent locks on active db). On completion: Switch the state of the active to inactive and from inactive to active db. I think this wont help for the higher network latency, tho. In my case it takes 25 min only refreshing). My "price_list" table is the source of all available prices.

Comment: It's often the case that you can fetch data from the server quickly, so if you can dump the contents as CSV, compute which rows need to be updated, and update those alone you may get substantially better performance. I've done this with hashes, as in each row has a SHA2-256 hash of its CSV row contents, and only rows where that data has changed (e.g. computed hash not found in database) get inserted. As easy as `SELECT row_hash FROM tablename` and then a series of `REPLACE INTO` operations.

Comment: You could probably compute a hash/diff on a 2.5MM line file in under a minute. You could even chunk that file up into pieces and run those hashes on multiple threads if you think that would help.

Comment: @tadman I updated my question with proper examples of how the tables look like. The import of the csv data takes around 1 minute and isn't really a big problem. In my opinion the problem is that I need to lookup "price_single_room", "price_double_room" (and for other columns like price_suite_room), in "price_list" which leads to a lot of additional queries per row. When I compute a hash for each price I still need to query my "offer" table and send a lot of queries for each column to find out what has changed.

Comment: That schema is crying out for better [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which might compact how much data you have to search, and how a few JOIN operations could get the results you need without a lot of work.

Comment: Recreating the table with `LOAD DATA` is _much_ faster than `REPLACE` or anything like that.

Comment: @RickJames yup, since `REPLACE` is basically just `DELETE + INSERT`. In my inactive table Im doing a `TRUNCATE` and refill the table. I think my import time was reduced drastically. But as I said the bottleneck is probably that I loop through each "offer" and need to execute 6 queries (for each column) to look after the best price for each category, which leads to the increased timings, when using a remote db server.

Comment: @user12794891 - See if it is possible to change from 6 queries _per offer_ into 6 queries _each handling all queries_.

Comment: Hi @RickJames! I just updated my function: Im building the queries for the six columns now, combine them and send them at once to the db server. MySQL then returns multiple rows (six), like so: `(SELECT field1, field2, FROM "price_list" WHERE x = condition ) UNION (SELECT field1, field2, FROM "price_list" WHERE condition) UNION (...)`. Its still very slow.

Comment: It is usually better to _start out_ with the table unpivoted.  That is, the 6 columns are represented in 6 rows.

Comment: Fyi: db server is a hosted instance of MariaDB in AWS, webserver is located in DE.

Comment: @user12794891 - It's in Deleware; where are you?  How long does `SELECT 1;` take?

Answer (score 0):

You have a table called `real; the following will replace it with a new table containing the fresh data.

```
CREATE TABLE t_new LIKE real;
LOAD DATA INFILE new ...;
RENAME TABLE real TO t_old,
             t_new TO real;
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

Notes:

```
⚈  The LOAD DATA step can be replaced by whatever process you have for importing the data.
⚈  The Loading is the only slow step.
⚈  The RENAME is atomic, so real always exists.
⚈  You may choose to delay the DROP in case the new data might be bad and you want to revert.
⚈  FOREIGN KEYs can be a hassle; it might be good not to have such.
```

-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#optimal_reload_of_a_table

Comment: Hi Rick,
im already refreshing the table "price_list" with "LOAD DATA", and its super fast. Imo the problem is with the "offers" table, when I'm updating the table on the same machine the whole process of updating prices in "offers" takes around 2-3 minutes, whereas if its on a remote machine it takes (now after many performance tweaks) around 13minutes, before 65+ minutes. The problem is in fact that I need to query multiple times against the remote table (finding the best price for offer XYZ in table "price_list") ... Actually I'm thinking about something like eager loading.